# When using an image server on a separate domain, should we link directly to the image URL and restrict crawling, or redirect through our domain?

Tags: google, web-crawlers, googlebot, images, cdn

I have a large number of images stored on a separate server, these URLs currently go through a 302 redirect. I think these additional pages are a total waste of time for Google to crawl.

At the moment it looks something like this:

Source page with image - `https://www.mysite.example/inspiration/events/guernsey/spring-walking-festival/`

Header Image source 302 redirect -

```
<img class="header-image" 
 src="/remote.axd/mysite.imageserver.example/media/5190/walking-festival-header.jpg?width=1200&height=600&mode=crop&anchor=bottom&quality=90" 
 srcset="/remote.axd/mysite.imageserver.example/media/5190/walking-festival-header.jpg)?width=320&height=450&mode=crop&anchor=bottom&quality=90 320w, 
 /remote.axd/mysite.imageserver.example/media/5190/walking-festival-header.jpg?width=640&height=450&mode=crop&anchor=bottom&quality=90 640w, 
 /remote.axd/mysite.imageserver.example/media/5190/walking-festival-header.jpg?width=1200&height=600&mode=crop&anchor=bottom&quality=90 1200w, 
 /remote.axd/mysite.imageserver.example/media/5190/walking-festival-header.jpg?width=1920&height=600&mode=crop&anchor=bottom&quality=90 1920w" 
 alt="" />
```

Example Page Google is redirected to - `https://mysite.imageserver.example/cache/8/d/a/1/5/1/8da151431f9eebd9a4c232809792fb464e628d9f.jpg`

Is the best process to update those URLs in the source code so they point to the final page but also no follow them so Google doesn't waste crawling?